# Angular smart table pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, smart-table

I am currently using : 
"angular-smart-table": "2.1.0"
"angular": "1.3.15"

When clicking on Smart table item, my application display item details in another page.
After visiting the item page i want to go back on the smart table page on the same pagination number (2 on the screenshot) :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu112.png)

**My problems :**

1. Don't know how to save currentPage (rootscope, paramter ?)

Here is the pagination view, which manage pagination :

```
<nav ng-if="pages.length >= 2">
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a ng-click="selectPage(1)" class="download">Début</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="selectPage(currentPage - 1)" class="download">&lt;</a></li>
    <li><a><page-select></page-select> / {{numPages}}</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="selectPage(currentPage + 1)" class="download">&gt;</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="selectPage(numPages)" class="download">Fin</a></li>
</ul>
```

2. Don't know how to call function "selectPage()" of the smartTable directive.

pageSelect Directive in 'smart-table-plugin-directive.js' :

`.directive('pageSelect', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<input id="test" type="text" class="select-page" ng-model="inputPage" ng-change="selectPage(inputPage)">',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, $rootscope) {
                    scope.$watch('currentPage', function (c) {
                        scope.inputPage = c;
                        scope.$root.page = c;
                    });
                }
            }
        }`

Thanks for responding

Y@ugy

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!--HTML-->
<table st-table="displayedUsers" st-safe-src="users" class="table table-hover  table-striped" style="background-color:white ">
  <thead class="bg-light panel-heading lter b-b ">
            ...<!--You can write your column name-->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
            ...<!--You can write your table info-->
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="10" class="text-left">
        <div st-items-by-page="10" st-pagination=""></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the example of stPersist directive: 

http://plnkr.co/edit/ekwiNt?p=preview`StPersist example`

1) you watch the table state and persist it somewhere (service, localstorage, session,etc) whenever it changes.
2) When the table is restored you read the value from your storage and call the slice function of the table controller

example:
[image: Screenshot]

**Response from :Laurent R**

Comment: there are juste one issue:
    +When I use WATCH for the whole table, That blocks other WATCH from smarttable and then I lost paging; instead of that I use a specific WATCH on an attribute that changes value when I'm In/Out of table and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

after experimenting lot of examples and practice I found best and easy to implement library to use data table in angularJS projects which provide,

1. sorting,
2. filtering
3. selection,
4. custom template,
5. editable,
6. pagination
7. searching,
8. themes,
9. column resizing,
10. draggable columns

http://ekokotov.github.io/object-table/

```html
<table  object-table
 from-url = "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/DXXROxj"
 data = "exportDataVariable"
 display = "10"
 headers = "Name, Eye color, Age,Balance,Company,Favorite Fruit"
 fields = "name,eyeColor,age,balance,company,favoriteFruit"
 sorting = "compound"
 editable = "true"
 resize="true"
 drag-columns="true">
</table>
```